# Sparse training of convolutional layers in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to train a CNN in Keras using convolutional layers like

```
x_1 = Conv2D(16, (kernel_size, kernel_size))(x_in)
```

x_in consists here 3 input feature layers, thus 3*16 = 48 kernels of kernel_size*kernel_size must be trained here. Suppose that I want that 5 out of these 48 kernels are completely 0 (so all elements of it), how can I train this efficiently?

Thanks in advance.

My total config is like this:

```
x_in = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))

x_1 = Conv2D(16, (kernel_size, kernel_size))(x_in)
x_1 = ReLU()(x_1)
x_2 = Conv2D(16, (kernel_size, kernel_size))(x_1)
x_2 = ReLU()(x_2)
x_3 = Conv2D(16, (kernel_size, kernel_size))(x_2)
return Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=x_3)
```

Comment: what is shape of ```x_in```?

Comment: 3 channels, the dimension of the channels is not known as I use a dataset with images with different resolutions

Comment: If I am not wrong 16 kernels of (3x3) must be trained not 48 right? 16 kernels will be shared across 3 channels making 48 convolution operations?

Comment: No, 48 kernels must be trained. One for every input channel-output channel combination.

Comment: In case of default convolution operation 16 filters (not 48) will be shared across channels making (3x3x16(weights) + 16(bias) = 448 trainable parameters). So are you are trying to customize this operation?

Comment: No, I am talking about 3(kernel)x3(kernel)x3(input)x16(output) (weights) + 16 (bias) parameters, so 48 kernels of 3x3. Of these 48, I want let's say 5 to have 0 at all the 9 positions.

Comment: ```tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3))``` will have 448 parameters as I said above. So what I am asking is are you customizing your Conv operation? because stuff you have mentioned is number of matrix multiplication not number of parameters.

Comment: No, it is not 448 as the amount of input channels is 3, not 1 because of the (x_in) that I write after the Conv2D. I am very sure about this :)

Comment: Create a sequential model add above layer and check ```model.summary()``` you'll have parameters details!

Comment: I have done that, the model summary tells me I am right.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vivek7mehta/c6e3227b134f3418c78dad2e0ee2ca52

Comment: oh sorry, I see the confusion now, you typed 3x3x16(weights) instead of 3x3x3x16(weights) but your outcome 448 was correct. The 3 and 16 I am giving here are just an example, I use other numbers, therefore my conclusion was correct in my model summary and you probably also meant the correct thing but just did a typo :) But still, for the case of 3 input channels and 16 output channels, the amount of total filters (all input-output combinations) is 48 and not 16. And it are 5 out of these 48 I want to be completely zero.

Comment: In that case could you post your model config? That will be helpful for providing exact answer!

Answer (score 2):

In that case you'll have to implement a custom convolution layer. You'll have to make a class which should be instance of keras's `Layer` class. This requires `call` method to be implemented for feed-forward calculation.
This might be something you are looking for.

```
class CustomConv2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, k=3):
      super(CustomConv2D, self).__init__()

      c1_1 = self.add_weight(shape=(k,k, 1, 5), initializer='zeros', dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)
      c1_2 = self.add_weight(shape=(k,k, 1, 11), initializer='zeros', dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
      self.c1 = tf.concat([c1_1,c1_2], axis=-1)

      self.c2 = self.add_weight(shape=(k,k, 1, 16), initializer='zeros', dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
      self.c3 = self.add_weight(shape=(k,k, 1, 16), initializer='zeros', dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x_1_c1 = tf.nn.conv2d(tf.expand_dims(inputs[:,:,:,0],-1), self.c1,padding='VALID')
        x_1_c2 = tf.nn.conv2d(tf.expand_dims(inputs[:,:,:,1],-1), self.c2,padding='VALID')
        x_1_c3 = tf.nn.conv2d(tf.expand_dims(inputs[:,:,:,2],-1), self.c3,padding='VALID')

        x_1 = tf.concat([x_1_c1,x_1_c2, x_1_c3], -1)
        return x_1
```

In this case we have three set of filters (16 for each channel), for first channel we are keeping 5 filters as non-trainable and rest 11 as trainable and rest of the 32 (for channel-2 and 3) filters are trainable.
This is instance of Layer class in keras and can be used just like any normal layer.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(CustomConv2D(3))

model.build(input_shape=(None,None,None,3))
I = tf.keras.Input((None,None,3))
model.call(I)
model.summary()
'''
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
custom_conv2d_2 (CustomConv2 (None, None, None, 48)    432       
=================================================================
Total params: 432
Trainable params: 387
Non-trainable params: 45
_________________________________________________________________
'''
```

As you can see we are not training 5 filters and hence 45 (3x3x5) non-trainable parameters
Here I have **not added bias** term. Which you can add further and customize your Conv layer. Also order of filters can be changed just make trainable parameter to False, and change `initializer` to something else for layers that you want to train.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks like something I was looking for, I will try it. One further question: you have now decided that the 5 non-trained kernels all come from the first input channel. Can the model train how many of these 5 start from the 1st, 2nd and 3th and to which output channels it is best that the pruning of the kernel takes place? Or is this too difficult?

Comment: If ultimately it is checking for every channel then there is nothing non-trainable ! Checkout this tensorflow [blog](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/05/tf-model-optimization-toolkit-pruning-API.html) on weights pruning while training.